# How to get Location message only when a specific activity is opened?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-location

In my AndroidManifest.xml file I have two activities:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have also set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

To be able to get user's location. According to my app logic, if I'm logged in, I'm redirected directly to the MainActivity, otherwise to the LoginActivity. First time I'm opening the app, LoginActivity is opened. Even if the logic for getting user location is present **only** in MainActivity, I'm asked for Location permission also when the LoginActivity is opened.

> To continue, turn on device location, which uses Google's location service

What should I do so I can get that message only when MainActivity is opened?

**Edit:** This is the code that I'm using:

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
builder.addLocationRequest(new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY));
builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MainActivity.this);
locationSettingsSuccessListener = locationSettingsResponse -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location enabled");
};
```

In the `onStart()`:

```
settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener(locationSettingsSuccessListener);
```

Comment: Probably you have put the code that requests the permission at MainActivity.onCreate(). And from there you starting LoginActivity. So you better use LoginActivity as "main" and "launcher" at the manifest. At the LoginActivity, if user already logged in, start the MainActivity

Comment: @ChristosThemelis Thanks for your comment but even if the `MainActivity` is empty, the message is still displayed. I already tried your solution but isn't help me because everytime I open the app, the LoginActivity is opened, then skipped because the user is logged in and only after that the MainActivity is opened.

Comment: What is the Android version of your device ?

Comment: @matdev I use Android 7.0

Comment: give us some code to understand. How and where you call the permission request?

Comment: @ChristosThemelis Just edited my question. Please see the code that I'm using.

Comment: Your edit does not contains the part of code that you requesting location permissions from user. At your question you are talking about permission, not location request. Finally, what you want when MainActivity starts? To enable location request or to ask user permissions ?

Comment: @ChristosThemelis It's about the Location request, sorry for the misunderstand. I want the Location request to take place only when the MainActivity starts and **not** when LoginActivity starts.

Comment: @ChristosThemelis Is this even possible?

Comment: @JohansBormman yes. The problem is at your app logic. Is your project public github or something else so I can check it?